# Splitting a list with odd length into two lists equal in length in Prolog

Tags: list, split, prolog

I am writing a predicate in Prolog to divide a list into two equal in length lists. For example :

```
spliting([a, b, c, d, e], L1, L2)
```

produces:

```
L1 = [a, b, c], L2 = [d, e].
```

My code:

```
parimpar(L, A, B) :-
    split(L, L, A, B).

split(B, [], [], B).
split([H|T], [_, _|T1], [H | T2], B) :-
    split(T, T1, T2, B).
```

But it is working only the list to split is of even length.
How can I resolve that?

Comment: A quick fix is adding `split([H|T], [_], [H], T)`.

Comment: Sorry I am asking. Where to add it?

Comment: Between the first and second clause of `split`.

Comment: Your title says to spit a list with odd length into two lists equal in length. How are you achieving that? `L1 = [a,b,c]` and `L2 = [d,e]` are not the same length.